# get haskell segmented list in the specified pattern

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I am supposed to get segment of Haskell list.

Input: `f3 [0,1,2,3]`

Expected output: `[[],[0],[0,1],[1],[0,1,2],[1,2],[2],[0,1,2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]`

I solved it like this but I can't get it into the specified pattern.

```
inits_ :: [a] -> [[a]]
inits_ [] = []
inits_ xs = xs : inits_ (init xs)

segments :: [a] -> [[a]]
segments [] = []
segments (x:xs) = inits_ (x:xs) ++ segments xs
```

Evaluating the expression:

```
segments [0,1,2,3]
```

Yields:

```
[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2],[0,1],[0],[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[2,3],[2],[3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've solved it by concatenating the inits of the tails.  In order words, you've taken the tails of [0,1,2,3]:

```
[0,1,2,3]
[1,2,3]
[2,3]
[3]
```

and expanded them to their inits:

```
[0,1,2,3]  -->  [0,1,2,3],[0,1,2],[0,1],[0]
[1,2,3]    -->  [1,2,3],[1,2],[1]
[2,3]      -->  [2,3],[2]
[3]        -->  [3]
```

and then combined those in order to get your final answer:

```
> segments [0,1,2,3]
[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2],[0,1],[0],[1,2,3],[1,2],[1],[2,3],[2],[3]]
```

What if you instead started with the inits (in reverse order):

```
[0]
[0,1]
[0,1,2]
[0,1,2,3]
```

and expanded them to their tails:

```
[0]        -->  [0]
[0,1]      -->  [0,1],[1]
[0,1,2]    -->  [0,1,2],[1,2],[2]
[0,1,2,3]  -->  [0,1,2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]
```

and combined those in order:

```
> segments [0,1,2,3]
[[0],[0,1],[1],[0,1,2],[1,2],[2],[0,1,2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]
```

That's missing the initial empty segment (as was your answer), but it's otherwise the order you want.

As a hint, this slightly modified version of `segments'` will combine the tails in the right order and will even add the empty segment in the base case:

```
segments' :: [a] -> [[a]]
segments' [] = [[]]
segments' xs = segments' (init xs) ++ tails_ xs
```

You just need to define `tails_` so it works like so:

```
λ> tails_ [0,1,2,3]
[[0,1,2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3],[3]]
```